# credit card security suggested scenario

Tags: credit-card

I need to know the best scenario for a merchant inserting client's credit cards and expiry dates to process recurring payment for these cards. What I have in mind (and want your expert suggestions please) is the following:

1. form to be filled with credit card information
2. normal post with https to a php page having function for encrypting the credit card with random encrypt key
3. saving the encrypted card and the key in different locations in mysql when processing the payment
4. getting the encrypted credit card and the key and use a decryption function to process the payment with curl to the gateway

credit card encrypt/decrypt sample:
http://www.walkswithme.net/credit-card-validation-and-encryption-using-php

do you have any comments on the above, or better scenario?

Comment: Whether you need to be PCI compliant or not, the [PCI guidelines](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/why_comply.php) are a good start for best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Your payment gateway should be able to provide you with a tokenized system for recurring payments where you submit the cc to the payment gateway once and they return an authorization code which you will use instead of a cc number for the recurring payments.

This is a far better solution than storing credit card numbers in any shape or form. Please contact your payment provider for advice before you consider copy/pasting encryption advice from the internets.